# jQuery iframe reloading by many elements with same ID?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Right now i am working on a simple HTML/Jquery page.
In my code i am trying to reload specific
Here is my code, check it out please:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#Reload" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
    $('#IframeReload')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
    });
 });
 }); 
</script>
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<iframe id="IframeReload" src="suggestions.php?id=<?PHP echo $membid;?>" target="_parent">Browser not compatible.</iframe>


<div id="Reload" class="tooltip1" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div id="Reload" class="tooltip2" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div id="Reload" class="tooltip3" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
```

As you can see i have many elements with ID "Reload".
With this code sample when i press ONLY THE FIRST shown element with id "Reload" the iframe is reloading like it supose to be reloaded, but when i click on anyone other div element with id "Reload" just nothing happens and that's the problem.

How i can make my jQuery code to reload the iframe by clicking on every element with id "Reload"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `IDs` should be unique. Period.

Comment: instead of IDs use class & then bind events on class. it will work. ID should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are referencing.

```
$("#Reload")
```

The above code selects the first element with that ID.

```
$("[id=Reload]")
```

This would allow you to select all elements with the same ID.

What you should do is apply the event by classname - this would be neater.

```
<div class="reload tooltip1" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div class="reload tooltip2" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div class="reload tooltip3" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.reload').on("click", function(){
            $('#IframeReload')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        });
     }); 
</script>
```

You should keep element ID attributes unique.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique on a page.

```
<div class="reload tooltip1" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div class="reload tooltip2" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div class="reload tooltip3" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.reload').click(function(){
            $('#IframeReload')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        });
     }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need unique IDs for every element in your page. What you should do is create a JavaScript function that reloads the page, and then assign the `click` listener on each div to the function.

Another way to do this is instead of using the ID, you can use a common class and then set the `click` listener for that class.

Comment: Talking, talking, no code. This is an incomplete answer. I suggest you tweak it before the downvoting starts.